# How to describe a discrete action space where one action has a continuous range?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'd like to construct an action space in gym with the following characteristics. Consider a machine that can either be OFF (value 0) or ON (value in the range [100, 400]) depending on the electrical power.

So an action should be sampled from a set containing the discrete value 0 and the range [100, 400]. In other words, `action_space.sample()` should return a value from the set {0, x} where x in [100, 400]. Does anybody know how to do this?